# Databinding in ListBox in windows phone 8.0

Tags: json, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox

I want to Load Data in ListView in Listbox from web services PHP API. It can't be able to load Data. Here is my JSON class:

```
public class Menu
    {
        public string Menu_ID { get; set; }
        public string Menu_name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Menu_image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is code for Parsing Json Data:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
```

How can I bind these Data to a ListBox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post questions for which you can find an answer by a google search: [msdn Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the information in the DataContext property, for example:

```
ListBox1.DataContext = root;
```

And you just need to design it. By the way, I think it's not okay:

```
public Menu Menu { get; set; }
```

Because the variable and the class share the same name.

More information:
[Quickstart: Data binding to controls for Windows Phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx)

Also, I suggest you to move to UWP (Universal Windows Platform) that is the future of any Windows development.